# Chrome Extension: chrome storage does not recognize obj["name" + i]

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find a tab name that I put into `chrome storage`. The names of different tabs are identified by the number after `tabNames`. For example, the tab names in the storage would be shown as `tabNames1, tabNames2`, etc.

When I try to iterate through the tabs to find the tab name, I am unable to use a variable to denote the number, and would result in undefined.

I'm trying to iterate through all of the tab names with a `for loop`, but I am not sure how to do it if I cannot use `i` in place of 1, 2, 3, etc.

EDIT: included more code

## background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInstall);
function onInstall()
{
    chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": 0});
}

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(storeTabs);

function storeTabs(command)
{
    if ("toggle-feature" == command)
    {
        chrome.storage.local.get("groupCount", function(group)
        {
            // current count of groups
            var groupCount = group.groupCount;

            var promptUser = prompt("Group name: ");

            if (promptUser != "" && groupCount != 0)
            {
                /* iterates through the names */
                for (var i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)
                {
                    chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i], function(anotherGroup)
                    {
                        var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName" + i];
                        console.log("group: " + anotherGroup["groupName" + i]);

                        chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items)
                        {
                            var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
                            console.log("storage: " + allKeys);
                        })
                        console.log("groupName: " + groupName);
                    })
                }
            }

            /* stores the number, name, and urls of the tabs, as well as the group name into an object for storage */
            else
            {
                var groupObject = {};

                /* stores all of the tab's information into an object and then puts object into storage */
                chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(tabs)
                {
                    /* gets each tab's name and url from an array of tabs and stores them into arrays */
                    var tabNamesArr = [];
                    var tabUrlsArr = [];
                    var tabCount = 0;

                    for (; tabCount < tabs.length; tabCount++)
                    {
                        tabNamesArr[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].title;
                        console.log("title of tab: " + tabs[tabCount].title);
                        tabUrlsArr[tabCount] = tabs[tabCount].url;
                    }

                    var groupName = "groupName" + groupCount;
                    groupObject[groupName] = promptUser;

                    var tabNames = "tabNames" + groupCount;
                    groupObject[tabNames] = tabNamesArr;

                    var tabUrls = "tabUrls" + groupCount;
                    groupObject[tabUrls] = tabUrlsArr;

                    var tabCount2 = "tabCount" + groupCount;
                    groupObject[tabCount2] = tabCount;

                    // puts object into storage
                    chrome.storage.local.set(groupObject);

                    // set-up for next group so last group isn't overwritten
                    chrome.storage.local.set({"groupCount": (groupCount + 1)});
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

## background.js console after calling command 3 times

```
group: undefined
background.js:68 storage: buttonCount,groupCount,groupName0,groupName1,tabCount0,tabCount1,tabNames0,tabNames1,tabUrls0,tabUrls1
background.js:63 group: undefined
background.js:68 storage: buttonCount,groupCount,groupName0,groupName1,groupName2,tabCount0,tabCount1,tabCount2,tabNames0,tabNames1,tabNames2,tabUrls0,tabUrls1,tabUrls2
```

Comment: that should work fine if there really is an entry in `storage.local` for key `tabName1`. can you provide code for reproducing the issue end-to-end?

Comment: Yeah, I've updated my post to include all of background.js and the results from the console

Comment: Your code doesn't create "tabName" + anything. It only creates "tabNames" array. Make sure you're using devtools debugger and Storage Area Explorer extension.

Comment: The example above was just to illustrate the problem, I don't use that in the code. Sorry for the confusion, I've removed the example and just have the background.js code now.

Comment: I believe the below answer addresses your issue. For future reference, it would have helped to also include the relevant parts of `manifest.json` and provide precise steps for reproducing the behavior ("invoke keyboard command XYZ 3 times", etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `i` as declared in `for (var i = 0; i < groupCount; i++)` is changing in the loop before your async callback provided in `chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i], function(anotherGroup)` is run.

So, when you want `var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName" + i];` to equate to:

```
var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName0"];
```

it's actually equating to

```
var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName1"];
```

One way to fix this in your example with minimal code changes is to use `bind` to create an anonymous function with a fixed value for `i` when invoking `chrome.storage.local.get`.

Try changing

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i], function(anotherGroup)
{
    var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName" + i];
    console.log("group: " + anotherGroup["groupName" + i]);

    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items)
    {
        var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
        console.log("storage: " + allKeys);
    })
    console.log("groupName: " + groupName);
})
```

to

```
chrome.storage.local.get(["groupName" + i], function(i, anotherGroup)
{
    var groupName = anotherGroup["groupName" + i];
    console.log("group: " + anotherGroup["groupName" + i]);

    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items)
    {
        var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
        console.log("storage: " + allKeys);
    })
    console.log("groupName: " + groupName);
}.bind(this, i))
```

(Note that only the first and last line in that updated code is actually modified from your original example code.)

Comment: Wow that's interesting! I'll make sure to add the manifest and be more specific next time, thank you again!